# Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be cardinal numbers where $\aleph_0\le\gamma$, $\alpha+\beta=\gamma$, and $\alpha<\gamma$. Then $\beta=\gamma$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be cardinal numbers. We define $\alpha+\beta=|S|$, where $S=A\cup B$ with $|A|=\alpha$, $|B|=\beta$, and $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
>
> 1. If $\alpha\le\beta$ and $\aleph_0\le\beta$, then $\alpha+\beta=\beta$.
> 2. If $\alpha+\beta=\gamma$, $\aleph_0\le\gamma$, and $\alpha<\gamma$, then $\beta=\gamma$.

---

**My attempt:**

*Lemma:* $\aleph_0\le\beta\implies \beta+\beta=\beta$ (I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916836/let-a-b-be-infinite-sets-such-that-a-cap-b-emptyset-and-a-b-then-a))

> We first prove claim 1:

We have $\beta\le\alpha+\beta\le\beta+\beta$ and $\beta+\beta=\beta$ by *Lemma*. Thus $\alpha+\beta=\beta$.

> We next prove claim 2:

We have $\alpha+\beta=\gamma$, then $\beta\le\gamma$. Assume the contrary that $\beta\neq\gamma$, then $\beta<\gamma$.

If $\alpha\le\beta$, then $\alpha+\beta=\beta$ by Claim 1. It follows that $\alpha+\beta=\beta<\gamma$, which is a contradiction.

If $\beta<\alpha$, then $\alpha+\beta=\alpha$ by Claim 1. It follows that $\alpha+\beta=\alpha<\gamma$, which is a contradiction.

Hence $\beta=\gamma$.

---

> Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!